# Pandas Dataframe: Get and Edit all values in a column containing substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have a dataframe, called stores, like this one:

| country | store_name |
| --- | --- |
| FR | my new tmp |
| ES | this Tmp is new |
| FR | walmart |
| ES | Target |
| FR | TMP |

and another dataframe, called replacements, like this one:

| country | original | replacement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ES | TMP | STORE |
| FR | TMP | STORE |
| FR | WALMART | IGNORE |

How would you go about getting and updating all values in the store_name column of the first dataframe according to the "rules" of the second one, when the substring in the original column is found (ignoring lower/upper case)?

For this example i'd like to get a new dataframe like this:

| country | store_name |
| --- | --- |
| FR | my new STORE |
| ES | this STORE is new |
| FR | IGNORE |
| ES | Target |
| FR | STORE |

I was thinking something like iterating the second dataframe and apply the change to the first one, like this:

```
for index, row in replacements.iterrows():
    stores['store_name'] = stores['store_name'].str.upper().replace(row["original"].upper(), row["replacement"])
```

It kind of works, but it's doing some weird things like not changing some strings. Also, I'm not sure if this is the optimal way of doing this. Any suggestions?

Reproducible inputs:

```
data = [['FR', 'my new tmp'], ['ES', 'this Tmp is new'], ['FR', 'walmart'], ['ES', 'Target'], ['FR', 'TMP']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['country', 'store_name'])

data = [['ES', 'TMP','STORE'], ['FR', 'TMP','STORE'], ['FR', 'WALMART','IGNORE']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['country', 'store_name','replacement'])
```

Comment: Can you provide the DataFrame constructors of the two inputs?

Comment: data = [['FR', 'my new tmp'], ['ES', 'this Tmp is new'], ['FR', 'walmart'], ['ES', 'Target'], ['FR', 'TMP']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['country', 'store_name'])

Comment: data = [['ES', 'TMP','STORE'], ['FR', 'TMP','STORE'], ['FR', 'WALMART','IGNORE']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['country', 'store_name',''])

Comment: Sorry, this is for the second one:     data = [['ES', 'TMP','STORE'], ['FR', 'TMP','STORE'], ['FR', 'WALMART','IGNORE']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['country', 'original','replacement'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `df1` and `df2`, you can use a crafted regex within [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
import re

s = df2.set_index(['country', 'store_name'])['replacement']

df1['store_name'] = (
 df1.groupby('country', group_keys=False)
    .apply(lambda g: g['store_name'].str.replace(f"({'|'.join(map(re.escape, s[g.name].index))})", lambda m: s[(g.name, m.group().upper())], regex=True, flags=re.I))
 )

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
  country         store_name
0      FR       my new STORE
1      ES  this STORE is new
2      FR             IGNORE
3      ES             Target
4      FR              STORE
```

Comment: This works great with the example I gave (just changed store_name to original in the 2nd line), but if I use it with my bigger dataframe, I get the following error. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/mit_scraping/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3970, in __setitem__
    self._set_item_frame_value(key, value)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/mit_scraping/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4100, in _set_item_frame_value
    raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that triggers the error?

Answer (score 1):

If obtaining a new dataframe as result is acceptable consider the following approach implying outer join of 2 initial dfs, grouping and regex replacement based on first found match within a group and *successful* replacement:

```
import re

def f(x):
    for r in x.itertuples(index=False):
        store_name, subs = re.subn(r.store_name_y, r.replacement, r.store_name_x, flags=re.I)
        if subs == 1:  # if there was successful replacement
            return store_name  # return the result immediately
    else:
        return r.store_name_x

res_df = df1.merge(df2, on='country', how='outer')\
    .groupby(['country', 'store_name_x'], sort=False)\
    .apply(f).droplevel(1).reset_index(name='store_name')
```

---

```
  country         store_name
0      FR       my new STORE
1      FR             IGNORE
2      FR              STORE
3      ES  this STORE is new
4      ES             Target
```